# I cannot see anything with my chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i am learning Bootstrap.
when i open the html with chrome,i cannot see anything.

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Navigation</title>
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first welcome to stack overflow! Second, consider looking into how to ask questions on stack overflow, which you can read more on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Third, learning bootstrap (or any front-end technology), I suggest using [Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/). A tool like this is great when you're testing out a piece of technology like boostrap. Here's your code in a [codeply project](https://www.codeply.com/go/HygIkvuYE6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm assuming you're not seeing anything in any other browsers either?

your html has no actual content.

try adding text to links and divs; see if that fixes it.  otherwise check the path to the bootstrap css and make sure it's loading correctly.

Comment: ah, i clean up  cache and now i can see it.Thank you.